# malformed module path "xxxx/xxxx/uuid" missing dot in first path element when migrating from GOPATH based dep to go mod

Tags: go, go-modules

```
$ go version
1.13.3
```

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
GOPATH
+---src
     +--- my-api-server
           +--- my-auth-server
                 +--- main.go
           +--- my-utils
                 +--- uuid
                       +--- uuid.go
```

`my-auth-server` uses `my-api-server/my-utils/uuid` as a depenency

Now, when I used the GOPATH based module system, this worked fine. But when using go modules, when I run `go run main.go` in `my-auth-server` it returned error:

```
build command-line-arguments: cannot load my-api-server/my-utils/uuid: malformed module path "my-api-server/my-utils/uuid": missing dot in first path element
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55347424/1218512

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `go.mod` file should be at the root of your project (in this case, `my-api-server/go.mod`).

The first part of the module path should be a domain/path. For example, the full path might be `github.com/your-github-username/my-api-server`. The error you're seeing is because the first part is not a domain (with a period). You don't have to publish the module to develop it, but you need to use a proper domain name.

Once you have a module path, you can import packages contained in that module using the full module path + "/" + the relative path of the package. For example,

```
import "github.com/your-github-username/my-api-server/my-utils/uuid"
```

Since `main.go` and `uuid` are contained in the same module, you don't need a `require` statement in the `go.mod` file to use the `uuid` package. You can import it like any other package and it will work.

I recommend using `go build` and running the resulting executable rather than using `go run` to make sure you include all of the files you need in the build process.

See https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules for a walkthrough of how to use Go modules, including the [second post](https://blog.golang.org/migrating-to-go-modules) in that series about how to convert a project to use modules.

Answer (score 3):

Check your import paths on your main.go file.

I had to call the entire import path:

```
github.com/[username]/[project-name]/views
```

instead of:

```
[project-name]/views
```

to make it work on my end.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to use a global package(non standard), there should be a dot('.') in the first part of package name. Probably expects dot('.') as it does in any URL, in this case github.com....which marks that as remote package.

If you want to use local package, then you need to use go module, then first part would be the name of you go module(name which you have used during initilization of your go module).

Example (as per the question):
Go to project root folder (in this case `../src$`) & run following command

```
go mod init myapiserver
```

This will create a ***go.mod*** & ***go.sum*** file.

Then to import uuid, you can simply use `myapiserver/my-utils/uuid` in import

```
import "myapiserver/my-utils/uuid"
```

then all the public functions(which starts with Capital letters) from `uuid.go` will be accessible in the current file

Answer (score 0):

upgrade go version with the latest or greater than 1.16.1.

`go version >=1.16.1 (required)`

for mac -

```
brew update
brew upgrade golang
```

for linux -
Remove Existing go, and Install the latest one.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Very unusual scenario, but I was working with an incorrect/out-of-date symlink `main.go`. Linking it to the correct file fixed that error.

Answer (score -4):

BECAUSE GO CANNOT FIND THE MODULE!!!

Do not put your project inside GOPATH... that is so confusing

Instead...

set in .bashrc:  export GO111MODULE=on

close all command line terminals, then re-open terminals

go to the project root folder

$ go mod init project_module_name

This will generate go.mod file

Install your packages with the version you want:
`go get -v github.com/golang/protobuf@v1.3.4`

Then run $ `go run main.go`

Now the go.mod file should record the package versions Golang will use to run and build...

Make sure your are using the correct package versions by checking the go.mod file! It should look like: github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.4

Comment: `Do not put your project inside GOPATH... that is so confusing` - That is a convention, which I particularly prefer.

Comment: Also, the error is `missing dot in first path element` not `cannot resolve module`

Comment: Ayush Gupta, the error is caused by incorrect module usage

Comment: incorrect package versions have incorrect file path => cause Golang not able to find the correct file to run or build