# net/http imports missing dot in first path element

Tags: go

When I run `go mod tidy` in the root of my project I get this message.

```
go-dispatch imports
        net/http imports
        golang_org/x/net/http/httpguts: malformed module path "golang_org/x/net/http/httpguts": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        net/http imports
        golang_org/x/net/http/httpproxy: malformed module path "golang_org/x/net/http/httpproxy": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        net/http imports
        golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack: malformed module path "golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        net/http imports
        golang_org/x/net/idna: malformed module path "golang_org/x/net/idna": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        net/http imports
        crypto/tls imports
        golang_org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305: malformed module path "golang_org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        net/http imports
        crypto/tls imports
        golang_org/x/crypto/curve25519: malformed module path "golang_org/x/crypto/curve25519": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        net/http imports
        net imports
        golang_org/x/net/dns/dnsmessage: malformed module path "golang_org/x/net/dns/dnsmessage": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        net/http imports
        net imports
        golang_org/x/net/lif: malformed module path "golang_org/x/net/lif": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        net/http imports
        net imports
        golang_org/x/net/route: malformed module path "golang_org/x/net/route": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres imports
        github.com/lib/pq imports
        crypto/x509 imports
        golang_org/x/crypto/cryptobyte: malformed module path "golang_org/x/crypto/cryptobyte": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/postgres imports
        github.com/lib/pq imports
        crypto/x509 imports
        golang_org/x/crypto/cryptobyte/asn1: malformed module path "golang_org/x/crypto/cryptobyte/asn1": missing dot in first path element
go-dispatch imports
        net/http imports
        net tested by
        net.test imports
        golang_org/x/net/nettest: malformed module path "golang_org/x/net/nettest": missing dot in first path element
```

I have tried everything from installing different versions of golang (1.11 - 1.13) and removed each as well. I have no idea what this issue means, but it seems to be a problem in the net/http package.

`go env` output:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/thakidd/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/thakidd/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GONOPROXY="xxx"
GONOSUMDB="xxx"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/thakidd/go"
GOPRIVATE="xxx"
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/thakidd/workspace/go-dispatch/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build783029481=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

I've also tried changing my GOROOT but that's set correctly as far as I can tell. I'm at a total loss as this is happening across several different projects. All have the same errors.

Comment: How did you install Go?

Comment: Install Go with the official installer from golang.org.  The brew installer is broken.

Comment: What's the output of `where go`?

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/q/59095179  and https://stackoverflow.com/q/58473656 ?

Comment: I installed go via apt on ubuntu | 

Not brew | 

`$which go` = `/usr/bin/go` |

I checked both of those before posting this question. The solution to both of those was to edit the enclosing app's structure or go.mod config. Neither are an option for built in packages like `net/http`

Comment: @iLoveReflection Thanks for the lead. After some digging i installed direct from tarball. Problem solved. snap and apt packages are no good right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@iLoveReflection Thanks for the lead.

After some digging I installed [direct from tarball](https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.13.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz#install). Problem solved. snap and apt packages are no good right now it seems.