# Can't access a private method in the same package for testing

Tags: go, testing

I have 2 files in the same package.

```
# my_package1/my_file1.go

func myFunc1() {
  //....
} 

# my_package1/my_file1_test.go

type MyPackageSuite struct {
  suite.Suite
}

func (s *MyPackageSuite) MyTest1() {
  //...............

  res1 := myFunc1()

  //...............
}
```

I run a test `go test my_package1/my_file1_test.go -v` and it returns `undefined: myFunc1`

But they're in the same package. Why the error? How to fix it? Making the method public isn't what I'm looking for.

**Update1**:

```
$ ls webhook
doc.go      webhook.go  webhook_test.go
```

Then

```
$ go test webhook
can't load package: package webhook: malformed module path "webhook": missing dot in first path element


$ go test webhook/webhook
can't load package: package webhook/webhook: malformed module path "webhook/webhook": missing dot in first path element

$ go test webhook/webhook.go
?     command-line-arguments  [no test files]


$ go test webhook/webhook_test.go 
# command-line-arguments [command-line-arguments.test]
webhook/webhook_test.go: undefined: myFunc1
FAIL  command-line-arguments [build failed]
FAIL
```

Comment: Do not run the test using file name. Either cd under the package and run go test, or run go test <full packageName>.

Comment: @BurakSerdar see my update

Comment: If it is complaining about import cycle, you're importing the same package. Don't do that. If you're using go modules, use full package path: go test moduleName/webhook. If not, use relative package dir: go test ./webhook. go test webhook tries to test a package named `webhook`, and since it does not have a hostname as first component, it assumes it is a stdlib package.

Comment: @BurakSerdar running `go test` from the directory of the package causes `import cycle not allowed in test`. Otherwise, **without this test with the private method**, it works. That is, this works if I don't use the test with the private method --> `go test webhook/webhook_test.go`

Comment: @BurakSerdar - no. Read my last comment.

Comment: The `go` tool works on packages (there are some modes to work with files, but they are best avoided in most cases). If you cannot run a simple `go test` (e.g. because of an import cycle or because you misspelled your package in test) then your package setup is **broken** and **must** be fixed. No arguing here. Go **forbidds** import cycles and **requires** one of two package names in _test.go files.

Comment: If you want to test the exported boundary of some `package p` and have a p_test.go file declaring itself as `package p_test` then you **cannot** access unexported stuff from p. This is _by_ _design_ and **cannot** be circumvented by ugly tricks. Just stop doing this.

Comment: ... See [relative import paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Relative_import_paths) ... *"a relative path can be used as a shorthand on the command line. If you are working in the directory containing the code imported as "unicode" and want to run the tests for "unicode/utf8", you can type `"go test ./utf8"` instead of needing to specify the full path."* But keep in mind what Volker said, for a file to be able to access an unexported identifier it must declare the same package as the file declaring the identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Try  `go test ./my_package1` to force the compilation of the all package.
Or at least a `go build` first.

The idea is to make sure `myFunc1()` was compiled before executing the test file.

---

The "`malformed module path`" "`missing dot in first path element`" suggests a [`go mod` file is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58563894/6309):

```
cd /path/to/project
go mod init project
go test ./webhook
```

Comment: @Totto Can you try `go test ./webhook`? Do you have a `go.mod` file in your project?