# Go import local package

Tags: go

I have a `main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    model "model"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func handler(...){
}
```

I try to import model which is in the directory `model` and the file is called `model.go`

It just contains:

```
package model

type xxx struct {
    xxx
}
```

I try to import this in the main but I have the error:

```
build: cannot load model: cannot find module providing package model
```

Comment: You are using go modules?

Comment: Try changing line # `8` to `model "./model"` or define paths in your `go.mod` file.

Comment: I have a go.mod file but it's not clear how I have to add it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing local packages within a go module (go 1.11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026284/accessing-local-packages-within-a-go-module-go-1-11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `go.mod` looks like this:

```
module github.com/meakesbia/myproject

go 1.14
```

then you need to import the module package using the full module reference:

```
import "github.com/meakesbia/myproject/model"
```

If it's an entirely local project then replace `github.com/meakesbia` with the model name from `go.mod` e.g.:

```
module meakesbia/myproject

go 1.14
```

```
import "meakesbia/myproject/model"
```

You don't need to add a `replace` directive to the `go.mod` file unless you're making local changes to a module that is imported from e.g. *github*.

Comment: Hi, it's fully local. So it's not on GitHub.

Comment: @tonys can you please check again whether the import without the `replace` directive will work fine in the case of _local project_?

Comment: @HamzaAnis, I double-checked before I edited the post and have just checked again. It seems fine - at least 'on my machine' :-)

Comment: You have this module under your `$GOPATH`?

Comment: @HamzaAnis: Nope - with Go modules you no longer use GOPATH, as per the official guide (https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) and sundry other blogs (e.g. https://blog.francium.tech/go-modules-go-project-set-up-without-gopath-1ae601a4e868). 

If it is set and/or you are using a 'src' directory structure that may be why you need a 'replace' directive in your go.mod.

Answer (score 11):

If your module `model` is not local then you can use Tonys answer and it will work fine but if you are using this module locally then you will need to add the paths in your `go.mod` file.

So for example, Local module `model` contains only `model.go` which has the following content

```
package model

type Example struct {
    Name string
}

func (e *Example) Foo() string {
    return e.Name
}
```

For this local module must have have to init the module with the command `go mod init model` and the content of the `./model/go.mod` will be

```
module model
go 1.13
```

**In the main module in which you are importing this module you need to add the following line**

```
require model v1.0.0
replace model v1.0.0 => {Absolute or relative path to the model module}
```

So, your `main` testing module's `go.mod` file will look like this

```
module main

require model v1.0.0
replace model v1.0.0 => ./model

go 1.13
```

By setting this up you can use this module in this `test` module with just `import  "model"`

Hence when testing the module with the main method

```
package main

import (
    model "model"
)

func main() {
    example := model.Example{
        Name: "Hello World",
    }
    println(example.Foo())
}
```

The output will be

```
Hello World
```

Comment: it works but it's complicated while calling methods across the packages. Each package have to have go.mod declaration, better way is to put them in vendor folder