# How to provide version number for go local packages to mention in `go.mod` file

Tags: go

My intention is to mention  local package in go.mod file, but stuck in package version part. (Go version is  `go1.14.4 linux/amd64`)

Error:

```
arun@debian:~/experiments$ go build
go: errors parsing go.mod:
/home/arun/experiments/go.mod:8: usage: require module/path v1.2.3
```

If blindly give a version number (for example : `github.com/kcarun/local_pkg/app v1.2.3` in `go.mod`, it gives unknown version error) while executing `go build`

`go.mod`:

```
module github.com/kcarun/gitlandfill

go 1.14

replace github.com/kcarun/local_pkg/ => /home/arun/experiments/local_pkg/

require (
        github.com/kcarun/local_pkg/app
)
```

`main.go`:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "local_pkg"

func main(){
        fmt.Println("Ok")
        app.SayHello()
}
```

`app.go`:

```
package app

import "fmt"

func SayHello(){
        fmt.Println("Is working!!")
}
```

Directory Structure :

```
arun@debian:~/experiments$ pwd
/home/arun/experiments
arun@debian:~/experiments$ tree
.
|-- go.mod
|-- local_pkg
|   `-- app.go
`-- main.go
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026284/accessing-local-packages-within-a-go-module-go-1-11)

Comment: `import "local_pkg"` 100% wrong. If that package lives in module  is github.com/kcarun/local_pkg you must import it like that. Note that the replace directive is wrong too: Import path do not end in /. Please read How to Write Go Code and stick to it.

Comment: go mod is supposed to work with version control via git, this feature of using a local package is mostly for dev but when your module works properly just push it and use version information from git

Comment: Hi @Volker as you suggested, I modified the code , but still not working. See the [Error](https://i.imgur.com/Pk8CYcw.png)

Comment: @Volker , Okay I started reading that document !!,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right way to import "local" package as

```
.
├── go.mod
├── local_pkg
│   └── app.go
└── main.go
```

is

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/kcarun/gitlandfill/local_pkg"

func main(){
    fmt.Println("Ok")
    local_pkg.SayHello()
}
```

, without declared it in `go.mod`:

```
module github.com/kcarun/gitlandfill

go 1.14
```

If the `package` declared different than directory name (for example: dir is `/home/arun/experiments/local_pkg` and pages is `app`), you should import package use directory name, but to call it use  package name:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/kcarun/gitlandfill/local_pkg"

func main(){
    fmt.Println("Ok")
    app.SayHello()
}
```

Comment: I tried with this suggested modification , but still getting error [https://i.imgur.com/Pk8CYcw.png]

Comment: @Arun - fixed => try.

Comment: It worked , there was a mistake from my side too, In local system my username is `arun` and in github it is `kcarun` this made some path issues in `go.mod` file and in my import statements