# Create and use local module with go.mod (go 1.15)

Tags: go

I want to use a functions in my `libGo.go`. All topics that I watched for solve my problem is to push my folder on GitHub and in my `go.mod`use line `require github.com/pseudo/project`. Last Information I don't put my project on my `GOPATH`.

Architecture:

```
.
├── go.mod
├── libGo
│   └── libGo.go
└── main.go
```

libGo.go

```golang
package libGo

import "fmt";

func Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello");
}

func Calcule(x, y int) int {
    return (x + y);
}
```

main.go

```golang
package main;

import (
    "fmt"

    "example.com/libGo/libGo"
);

func main()  {
    fmt.Println("I'm main function");
    libGo.Hello()
}
```

go.mod

```golang
module example.com/libGo/libGo

go 1.15
```

error message:

```
package command-line-arguments
    imports example.com/libGo/libGo
    imports example.com/libGo/libGo: import cycle not allowed
```

I am a beginner at Golang, so if you can explain to me with an example and a description of why what I have done doesn't work I would be grateful.

Topics Read(first answer with 46 votes): [Accessing local packages within a go module (go 1.11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026284/accessing-local-packages-within-a-go-module-go-1-11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your module is called `example.com/libGo` and the package within this module is called `libGo`. Therfore the full package name would be `example.com/libGo/libGo`.

You would need to adjust the import or the module name. When you adjust the import to `example.com/libGo/libGo`, the module name must stay `example.com/libGo`. When you adjust the module name to `example.com`, the import name must stay `example.com/libGo`. Adding the package name to both ones puts you in the same situation as before.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but I have other problem, I edit my ask for explain my new bug @svenwltr

Comment: I litre question. I don't know if I should create a topic for this, but what exactly is ```example.com```? is it a website? Finally if I understand your new answer correctly, I just need to change the path in my ```main.go``` file import. I'm sorry my question is maybe stupid for you

Comment: The module name is a globally unique identifier for this project/module. Also it is used by Golang to fetch the module, so it knows where to get to module from. In your case it would make sense to call it `github.com/pseudo/project`.